# How to convert complex Postgres SQL query / subqueries to active record in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application requires a text field and its translations to be displayed all at once in the edit view.
Available translations and even the list of configured languages evolve over time, so that the edit view must display the available translations, and create empty fields for missing ones.

Thus, the _form.html.erb file contains nested fields to handle these translations.

```
<%= f.fields_for translation_fields, translations.sort_by { |e| [ e.language == current_language.to_s ? 0 : 1, e.language ] } do |locution| %>
```

But this only allows handling of existing translations.

To allow additional languages support, I need to create a right-join with the list of languages, and initialise empty records accordingly. The corresponding SQL query for providing translations fields for the *name* of *Playground* object with id=*555* is:

```
select 555 as document_id, 'Playground' as document_type, 'name' as field_name, property as language,
case when property = language then existing_translations.id else null end as id,
case when property = language then existing_translations.translation else null end as translation
from
(select * 
 from dqm_app.translations 
 where document_id = 555 and field_name = 'name' and document_type = 'Playground'
) as existing_translations
right outer join 
(select property
from dqm_app.parameters inner join dqm_app.parameters_lists on parameters.parameters_list_id = parameters_lists.id 
where parameters_lists.CODE = 'LIST_OF_LANGUAGES') as langues on property = language
```

As a result, we can see herunder that only a french translation exists, and other translations are to be created:
[image: Translations for Playground's 555 name]

To reproduce this in Active Record, I created subqueries, which I need to join:

```
  <% existing_translations = Translation.where({document_id: document_id, document_type: document_type, field_name: field_name}) %>
  <% languages = Parameter.where("parameters_list_id = (select id from parameters_lists where code = 'LIST_OF_LANGUAGES')") %>
```

How can I create a right outer join between these subqueries?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

> Note: I finally solved any complex query by using AREL, starting with
> this [cheat sheet.](https://devhints.io/arel)

Comment: You might want to add the DBMS you're currently using.